# Спрятать консоль в приложении unicode кодировки

Tags: c, winapi

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

Точка входа

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

Компилятор выкидывает ошибку: неразрешенный внешний символ main.
Пробовал писать так, вышло много неразрешенных символов типа winapi. При добавлении библиотек, выкидывает что не найдено (хоть тот же Kernel32.dll)

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:wmain")
```

Правка:
Почитал по-больше, понял, что mainCRTStartup это точка входа библиотеки инициализации от microsoft. И судя по всему это мультибайтовая точка входа. А мне нужно юникодная. Как изнать ее имя или может каким-то образом заставить подгружать какую-то другую библиотеку вместо нее?

Comment: Если у Вас visual studio, просто создайте неконсольное приложение через мастер и не заморачивайтесь.

Comment: @mega приложение крупное и переносить много. Проще прописать 1 команду (вот и не знаю какую) чтобы получить нужный результат

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем ясен вопрос, при чем тут Unicode?

Comment: А так вообще в настройки проекта и в секции C/C++ выбрать опцию кто есть core system для приложения, дословно непомню имя параметра, но найдёте, надо выбрать winapi

Comment: @NewView не нашел такого)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение.
Как и думал, нужно было прописать точку входа для библиотеки юникод кодировки.
То есть вместо mainCRTStartup нужно прописать wmainCRTStartup.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:wmainCRTStartup")
```

Источник ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342388/how-to-force-the-visual-studio-to-use-the-wmain-instead-of-main